# Redux-form field class property instead of name

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I've done some research but didn't find anything related to this.

Is it possible to use an ES6 class:

```
class User {
  name;
  email;
}

const user = new User();
```

and then use it in `<Field name={user.name} />`?

Comment: Have you tried that?

Comment: Got to confess I didn't, I'll give it a try, thanks.

Comment: Okay, so I tried that, but nothing happens, I'm able to use the input (Material UI - Select in this case), but the value is not assigned.